# How to update a record in a Gridview

Tags: c#, sql, gridview

When I try to update a record in a `GridView`, the following code doesn't update the record, but it doesn't throw any errors either.

```
        protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        string index = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text; //DwgRegID

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MEHDI-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PIMS;Integrated Security=True");

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            string sql = "UPDATE dbo.Dwg_Register SET Ref = @Ref, Dwg_Ref = @Dwg_Ref,Title = @Title, Dwg_Received_Date = @Dwg_Received_Date, Rev = @Rev, Trade = @Trade, type1=@type1,Produced_Date=@Produced_Date,Produced_By=@Produced_By,Submittal_Ref=@Submittal_Ref,Issued_To=@Issued_To,Date_Issued = Date_Issued, Purpose = @Purpose, status1=@status1,Action_Date=@Action_Date where DwgRegID=N'" + index + "'";

            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = sql;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Ref", txtRef.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Dwg_Ref", txtDwgRef.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Title", txtTitle.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Dwg_Received_Date", txtDwgReceivedDate.Text == "" ? DBNull.Value : (object)txtDwgReceivedDate.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Rev", txtRev.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Trade", ddlTrade.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@type1", ddlType.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Produced_Date", txtProducedDate.Text == "" ? DBNull.Value : (object)txtProducedDate.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Produced_By", ddlProducedBy.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Submittal_Ref", txtSubmittalRef.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Issued_To", ddlIssuedTo.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Date_Issued", txtDateIssued.Text == "" ? DBNull.Value : (object)txtDateIssued.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Purpose", ddlPurpose.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@status1", ddlStatus.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Action_Date", txtActionDate.Text == "" ? DBNull.Value : (object)txtActionDate.Text));
            //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DwgRegID", index));


            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Close();
            }
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

            SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source= MEHDI-PC\\SQLExpress; Initial Catalog=PIMS; Integrated Security=True");
            string sql1 = "SELECT DwgRegID,Ref,Dwg_Ref,Title,Dwg_Received_Date,Rev,Trade,type1,Produced_Date,Produced_By,Submittal_Ref,Issued_To,Date_Issued,Purpose,status1,Action_Date from dbo.Dwg_Register";
            con1.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql1,con1);
            DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds1);
            GridView1.DataSource = ds1; 
            GridView1.DataBind();
            if (con1.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con1.Close();
            }


            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;

            GridView1.DataBind();

            MultiView1.SetActiveView(ViewGrid);

            lblUpdate.Text = "Record updated sucessfully.";


    }
```

When I run the following SQL query in SSMS:

```
UPDATE dbo.Dwg_Register
SET Ref=4
from dbo.Dwg_Register
where DwgRegID=23
```

this command does store value 4 into dbo.Dwg_Register. But this command is not storing values into sql table from the GridView.

My EditRow function code is as following:

```
            protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {

        MultiView1.SetActiveView(ViewGrid);

        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

        GridView1.DataBind();
```

}

This `RowEditing` function changes `RowState` in the `GridView` to edit-mode. But when I edit a cell value in the `Gridview` and press update button to store the new value to Sql table, Update function doesnt do it. This code neither throws any errors. Please help me identify where I might be going wrong. 
  Thanks.

Comment: About the error in SSMS: you have to set up all the parameters that you're doing in code in SSMS as well. Otherwise, you'll get that error. For example, you'd do something like `declare @ref varchar(30)` for the `@ref` parameter.

Comment: In SSMS, put the real values (not as parameters) as they are on the form and check if the query goes thru or gives an error. I guess you data is ill-formed for the query to run through.

Comment: check your database connection.

Comment: @ridoy connection is ok. Code is unable to read text from the edit-row cell and update it.

Answer (score 2):

Do error checking before you insert data.

That error is telling you that `txtRef.Text` does not have a value, but that a value is required.

Once you finish error checking for the `Ref` value, you should carry on through all of your other values as well.

You don't want to create a mess in your database.

**UPDATE:**

Make sure your `GridView` only updates the correct row types.

I do not really like using the `AddWithValue` tool, because it seems like it prevents people from understanding their database. Your `Add(new SqlParameter(` techniques essentially are doing just that.

For example, these two lines produce identical results:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ref", txtRef.Text);

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Ref", txtRef.Text));
```

What is `@Ref` in your database? `Integer`? `varchar(50)`? Obviously, there would be a big difference in how the database would treat the two.

If it were an `integer`, it should really be written as:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Ref", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtRef.Text.Trim());
```

If it were a `varchar(50)`, it should really be written as:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Ref", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtRef.Text.Trim();
```

Since I do not know anything about your database, I was left using `AddWithValue`, but I would strongly recommend looking at the design of your database tables, then match up your `SqlParameters` to how they are designed.

I'd also suggest using a `const` SQL Connection String, since your database will not be changing while your program is using it:

```
private static string m_sqlConn = "Data Source=MEHDI-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PIMS;Integrated Security=True";
```

I also created a `static` **DbSafe** method to "message" the data before it gets inserted. A method dedicated to this allows you to easily channel all of your data to make sure it is safe. Also, modifying the method later to add more functionality is easy to do and instantly translates to all of the code you use it in.

```
private static object DbSafe(object value) {
  if ((value != null) || (value != DBNull.Value)) {
    string strVal = value.ToString();
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(strVal)) {
      return strVal.Trim();
    }
  }
  return DBNull.Value;
}
```

There also is no reason for you to be making two (2) separate SQL objects (`SqlCommand` and `SqlDataAdapter`) to perform your task.

Here is how I wrote my modified version:

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e) {
  if (GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
    string index = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text; //DwgRegID
    string sqlUpdate = "UPDATE dbo.Dwg_Register SET " +
      "Ref=@Ref, Dwg_Ref=@Dwg_Ref, Title=@Title, Dwg_Received_Date=@Dwg_Received_Date, " +
      "Rev=@Rev, Trade=@Trade, type1=@type1, Produced_Date=@Produced_Date, " +
      "Produced_By=@Produced_By, Submittal_Ref=@Submittal_Ref, Issued_To=@Issued_To, " +
      "Date_Issued=Date_Issued, Purpose=@Purpose, status1=@status1, Action_Date=@Action_Date " +
      "WHERE DwgRegID=N'" + index + "'";
    string sqlSelect = "SELECT DwgRegID, Ref, Dwg_Ref, Title, Dwg_Received_Date, Rev, Trade, type1, Produced_Date, Produced_By, Submittal_Ref, " +
      "Issued_To, Date_Issued, Purpose, status1, Action_Date " +
      "from dbo.Dwg_Register";
    var table = new DataTable();
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlUpdate, new SqlConnection(m_sqlConn))) {
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ref", DbSafe(txtRef.Text));
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dwg_Ref", DbSafe(txtDwgRef.Text));
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", DbSafe(txtTitle.Text));
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dwg_Received_Date", DbSafe(txtDwgReceivedDate.Text));
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rev", DbSafe(txtRev.Text));
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Trade", DbSafe(ddlTrade.Text));
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type1", DbSafe(ddlType.Text));
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Produced_Date", DbSafe(txtProducedDate.Text));
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Produced_By", DbSafe(ddlProducedBy.Text));
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Submittal_Ref", DbSafe(txtSubmittalRef.Text));
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Issued_To", DbSafe(ddlIssuedTo.Text));
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date_Issued", DbSafe(txtDateIssued.Text));
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Purpose", DbSafe(ddlPurpose.Text));
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status1", DbSafe(ddlStatus.Text));
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action_Date", DbSafe(txtActionDate.Text));
      //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DwgRegID", index));
      try {
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.CommandText = sqlSelect;
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        table.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
      } catch (SqlException err) {
        Response.Write(err.Message);
      } finally {
        cmd.Connection.Close();
      }
    }
    GridView1.DataSource = table;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    MultiView1.SetActiveView(ViewGrid);
    lblUpdate.Text = "Record updated sucessfully.";
  }

}
```

Further, you will notice above that I added a `try/catch/finally` block that only catches `SqlException` errors, then it immediately closes the database connection.

I'm not sure what your `GridViewEditEventArgs` is doing and/or if it hurts anything, so I left it alone.

I hope that helps. It took entirely too long to explain.

Comment: You are correct. I did the debugging checkpoint thing and found out that txtRef.Text has no value like all other fields in the record. I am wondering why. I have updated my question (added `RowEditing` function). `RowEditing` function changes the `RowState` to edit mode but my update function is unable to read from the edit-mode row cell and then store that value to `Sql` table. Hope you understand my problem. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: I added a GREAT BIG update section with lots of explanation. Please +1 it if that helps, and mark it if it solves your problem.